# image editor to create texture atlas

Tags: asset-management

While I am slowly learning how to build an android game, I would like to build images for a game, especially texture atlas.

But the only image handling system I am familiar with is Photoshop. And I am not sure it is a good tool to organize images and to get coordinates for game dev.

Is there any good tool for this purpose? If photoshop is still good for this, any reference to show how to do it would be appreciated.

UPDATE: the second question was [answered by this](http://richardjdare.com/blog/2009/08/texture-atlas-maker/) But still want to hear more options.

UPDATE2: In case you are using libgdx, I found [it does the packing for you](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sprite Sheet Packer](https://github.com/nickgravelyn/SpriteSheetPacker) is a tool initially thought for XNA, but since it exports a PNG along with a TXT/XML with the sprite coordinates (and is easily extended via plugins) it may suit your requirements.

Comment: @Paul, Remember to mark this the correct answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one [Sprite Sheet Maker](http://www.texturepacker.com/sprite-sheet-maker/). It's a bit [more advanced](http://www.texturepacker.com/features/) than Sprite Sheet Packer, but it's not free, *unless* you're a blogger or a framework developer - interesting license.